# give fixed path to file in Java project (Netbeans)

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a Java project generating jasper reports, what I do is I give path of a file (report) and run my project it runs fine, but when I have to give JAR file to my friend, it always need that file to be placed in that specific folder according to which my code get's the file path and then have to place file there, my code is below to give some idea

```
public void generateReport(String dateStart, String dateEnd) {
    InputStream stream = null;
    Connection connection = null;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/app", "root", "");
    stream = new FileInputStream(new File("").getAbsolutePath() + "/reports/logReport.jrxml");
    JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(stream);
    jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, connection);

    //frame.getContentPane().add(dateSetter, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JRViewer300(jasperPrint), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setSize(900, 600);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    isVisible = true;
    connection.close();
    stream.close();
    }
```

within code it get the file from the path as given

> /reports/logReport.jrxml

but when I put JAR file somewhere else and run it, it gives error that

> C:\Desktop\reports\logReport.jrxml cannot find path specified.

I know it's due to code part `new File("").getAbsolutePath()` but I need to know how to make it so that it always get the file path from within project! So that I don't always have to place that particular file there!

Comment: Where is `reports` folder located in your machine and in your friends machine? and will it be always at same location?

Comment: reports folder is inside the project, now I don't get why it doesn't get the path from that project? or what I have to do so that it always pick that path as it picks path for all other reports placed in that folder

Comment: First of all you should be using relative path to get hold of that file. Second as you are making jars you should be using `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("file name");`.

Comment: the file name is supposed to be only file name or complete path? yet I followed and getting this error "java.util.MalFormedUrlException"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make it an absolute path to the same directory always you just specify the entire path.

```
stream = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/path/to/my/reports/logReport.jrxml"));
```

If you want it relative to the directory where your jar is running.

```
stream = new FileInputStream(new File("path/to/my/reports/logReport.jrxml"));
```

If instead you are looking to load the file from your Jar itself, you need to do it differently.

```
stream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream.("/path/to/my/reports/logReport.jrxml");
```

Comment: but what when i send that JAR to someone and it picks all files which are there in SRC folder but not the one in folder I created?

Comment: Wait, so you want the files from within your own jar? or a file on the computer?

Comment: no no I meant to say that I have created a new Report file (logReport) and I just want this file to be picked as others are, without any change of path each time I send this jar file to someone or place JAR file to some other folder

Comment: and yes I mean to pick that file from my JAR file not from specific location from my computer :)

Comment: Revised the answer, you need to use getResourceAsStream

Comment: not helping anyway :(, getting exception of "java.util.MalFormedUrl Exception" in your last suggestion

Comment: What are you using as your path exactly, it should start with "/" and be the exact path within your jar.  For example if I have an image1.png in my Images folder in the jar. "/Images/image1.png", case matters, as does the leading "/"

Comment: this is what I used and got exception stream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/reports/com/openbravo/reports/logReport.jrxml");

Comment: Thanks bro, worked finally ... I was placing wrong path but figured out after you mentioned about JAR path, you saved my day .. Thanks once again ;)

Answer (score 0):

Better you read the file form a specified location

Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15840554/java-cannot-read-from-file/15840713#15840713) to read the file from a specified location.

but if the same code is running on a server you have to specify the path relative to the root directory where the server is running

```
 String location = "/opt/reports/";
 String filename = "logReport.jrxml";

 File file = new File(location + filename);
```